# Static block not visible under admin panel->cms->static blocks

Tags: magento-1.7, static-block, programmatically, upgrade-script

I want to add a static block programmatically.
The way I'm trying to do that is next:

- I created file `data-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php` (there were none other
     files except data-install...) inside setup directory `app\code\local\[theme]\Customizations\data\[theme]​_customizations_setup`
- Added this code:

```
$stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('gt' => 0))->getAllIds();

foreach ($stores as $storeId) {
    $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
        ->setIsActive(1)
        ->setTitle('Test CMS Static Block')
        ->setIdentifier('cms_block_test')
        ->setContent('<!-- edit me -->')
        ->setStores(array($storeId))
        ->save();
}
```

After that, I changed `config.xml` version 1.0.1

Cleared all Magento cache

But my static block won't show under CMS > Static Blocks.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Did the `data-install-1.0.0.php` run in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think by that. Is there a way to run it? Would it overwrite any data if I do run it?

Comment: Question rephrased: Did the other data script(s) run successfully in the past? If not, this is not an issue with the current script but with your module setup. Also check if your module's resource identifier shows up in `core_resource` table.

Answer (score 1):

All Cms blocks are linked to one or more stores. Perhaps setting the store ID's will help:

```
->setStores(array($storeId))
```

Normally I build the code like this in my install/upgrade scripts:

```
$stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('gt' => 0))->getAllIds();

foreach ($stores as $storeId) {
    // Block creation code goes here
}
```

Was the block even added to the database? If it was, try to find the differences between the records to a block that you have added through the admin interface.

If not, then your script has probably not even run. You could add a log line somewhere (`Mage::log('Data upgrade @ ' . __FILE__)`) and see if it has appeared in your `var/log/system.log`.

Also check if the version of your module isn't yet at "1.0.1" by checking the version in the `core_resource` table.

If the version in the `core_resource` table is "1.0.1" or higher you could do two things

- Update the record in the `core_resource` table to "1.0.0" version (don't know what the side effects might be)
- Update your script and the `config.xml` to be version "1.0.3" so that Magento sees a newer version of the module and kicks off the upgrade

Comment: Updated the code, still nothing.

Comment: Updated the answer with some things you could check/do

Comment: I have no access to Magento DB so I can't check any tables. Will check for logs.

Comment: Logs are out of the question too :/. For some reason, I can't download them to check them out. FileZilla throws error. Any other way maybe?

Comment: You could upload another script to the root, like "test.php" where you query the DB for it (to see if it exists or to check `core_resource` table)? IMO you should have a certain amount of access to be able to properly develop something...

Comment: Can't argue that. Will try that ASAP.

Comment: Would this be a good query:

$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                    $productTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');

                    $sqlQuery = sprintf('SELECT * FROM core_resource', $productTableName);
                    $results = $read->fetchAll($sqlQuery);
                    
                    print_r($results);

And why I can't format this as code?

Comment: In the result, I get [theme]_customizations_setup version to be 1.0.2 while my upgrade script is at 1.0.1.

Comment: Update: tried to change my config.xml version and create a new upgrade script (1.0.1-1.0.2) to match that [theme]_customizations_setup version, but no luck.

Comment: You can update the record in the `core_resource` table to "1.0.0" or you could change your upgrade version to "1.0.3" (always higher then the one in `core_resource` to get Magento to recognize a newer version and kick off the upgrade)

Comment: @7ochem: The side effects of downgrading a `core_resource` entry are obvious. You will trigger data definition statements that were executed before, most likely causing (PDO) exceptions.

Comment: @mam08ixo, yes agreed. But in this case there weren't any scripts belonging to these versions. Btw I always built my scripts with checks so they are executable multiple times without any exceptions occurring

Comment: @7ochem - we changed [theme]_customizations_setup in the database, and it worked :). Thanks everybody.

Comment: Great! I hope my answer here has helped you out